# Inconsistent auto-layout rendering

Tags: swift, autolayout

There are a few issues with auto-layout that seem to present some inconsistencies from one scene to the other of my SpriteKit game:

Firstly, despite using the same piece of art for the ground in the first and second scenes, the artwork appears way smaller in the first. I am not sure how this is possible. They are both PNG files and the two scenes that hold the images are .swift, and I loaded the exact same images into imagesx.cassets. Yet when the first scene opens, the ground node is shorter and thinner than in the second scene (which I created first).

The other inconsistency is In my second scene when I use:

```
self.groundbar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
self.groundbar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + (self.groundbar.size.height) / 2)
```

The groundbar nestles precisely at the bottom of my screen, halfway through the middle of the groundbar (as indicated by the y-value).

Now, when I try this SAME code on the first scene, the ground is nowhere on the screen. I thought this might be due to the strange fact that the ground renders smaller in the first scene, but then it shouldn't matter because it's auto-layout and is referencing the specific characteristics of the node.

It seems like I'm almost dealing with two separate sets of auto-layout constraints or something. The first scene IS a physicsworld, and the second scene IS NOT, but when I removed that the ground in the first scene still did not render properly.

Even when I try to change the anchorPoint, the texture of the node moves visually, but the collision physics stays the same.

Why the major difference in auto-layout? 
Why are my two pieces of art different sizes when rendered in the same scene despite being the same pieces of art?

Comment: You can't use AutoLayout with Sprite Kit - AutoLayout is only for UIKit. Regarding your problem, have you checked the `scaleMode` and `size` of each scene?

Comment: Well The first scene loads up right after the Launch Screen. I have a node, that when clicked, initializes the second scene. The code I used for this was: scene.scalemode = .ResizeFill and scene.size = skView.bounds.size

Comment: Are you using a different `scaleMode` for each scene? That would definitely cause objects to look different between scenes.

Comment: I'm a beginner and am not quite sure what you mean by this. Is there a way I can check the scaleMode?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check which scaleMode is being used in the game's view controller. Make sure that the scaleModes are the same (there are three scaleModes: .AspectFill, .AspectFit and.ResizeFill). Next, make sure the anchorPoints match up (by default, the anchorPoints are (x: 0, y:0). Both things can be checked in the game's ViewController.